# Are the organizer and isOrganizer Attributes in MS-Graph event working?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the MS Graph API to create a new event with a technical user on behalf of a resource. The event is created, but the organizer and isOrganizer Attributes are not considered or ignored in the response.

I tried multiple requests as well as in 'v1.0' and 'beta' mode. In this SO question [How to create event where current user not organizer using Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356878/how-to-create-event-where-current-user-not-organizer-using-microsoft-graph-api) it is stated that this is not implemented at the time of the original post (2016). But I didn't find anything in the Graph-API docs, saying that this would not work.

This is the request body:

```
{
                "subject": "Instant Meeting: " + user_name,
                "body": {
                    "contentType": "HTML",
                    "content": "Dieser Termin wurde vom Konferenzraum eingestellt"
                },
                "isOrganizer": "false",
                "organizer" : {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "address":user_email,
                        "name": user_name
                    }
                }, 
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": start,
                    "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": end,
                    "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
                },
                "location":{
                    "displayName": room.get('name'),
                    "locationEmailAddress": room.get('email'),
                    "locationType" : "conferenceRoom"
                },
                "attendees": [
                    {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "address":user_email,
                        "name": user_name
                        },
                    "type": "required"
                    },
                    {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "address":room.get('email'),
                        "name": room.get('name')
                        },
                    "type": "resource"
                    }
                ]
                }
```

The relevant parts of the response are:

```
response.get('organizer')

{'emailAddress': {'address': 'testraum-nichtbuche...t-mail.de', 'name': 'TestRaum - NICHT BUCHEN'}}
'emailAddress': {'address': 'testraum-nichtbuche...t-mail.de', 'name': 'TestRaum - NICHT BUCHEN'}
__len__: 1

response.get('isOrganizer')

True
```

If this worked properly, I would expect the 'organizer' to be user_email and the flag to be set to False.

Can anyone provide a working example for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior has not changed. The `organizer` and `isOrganizer` properties cannot be defined by the caller, they are automatically assigned by Exchange:

- [setting event organizer with Outlook Calendar REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462270/setting-event-organizer-with-outlook-calendar-rest-api)
- [Outlook Calendar Rest API (create meeting using /me/events request with change organizer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787080/outlook-calendar-rest-api-create-meeting-using-me-events-request-with-change-o)
- [outlook.com rest api incorrect organizer email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089878/outlook-com-rest-api-incorrect-organizer-email)
- [How to create event where current user not organizer using Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356878/how-to-create-event-where-current-user-not-organizer-using-microsoft-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to set up an organizer via API. It can be done via extended properties.

There are 3 properties:

1. [2.1016 PidTagSentRepresentingName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/34c5170c-5c81-4a85-8cc8-31ae98d7f58c) - the Name of the organizer.
2. [2.1012 PidTagSentRepresentingAddressType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/759bcd52-7ab4-4344-9c69-c84864d34d26) - the Address Type. Usually SMTP or EX.
3. [2.1013 PidTagSentRepresentingEmailAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/f3c1c713-509b-4c93-9531-346d8621b36e) - the Address of the organizer.

So, if you want to set up the new organizer, you should set all 3. Please note that the id equals the **Property ID** of the relevant property. And you want to set AddressType as **SMTP** if you setting the SMTP.

PATCH request like that should work:

```
{
  "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
    {
        "id": "String 0x0042",
        "value": "Updated Organizer"
    },
    {
        "id": "String 0x0064",
        "value": "SMTP"
    },
    {
        "id": "String 0x065",
        "value": "updated@organizer.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is how it looks in Graph Exlorer: [image: organizer_patch]

And then you can see new organizer in the OWA:
[image: new_oganizer]

Comment: Thanks [@Vadim Iarovikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978002/vadim-iarovikov) for a great answer, it is the only way I can see to set a different organizer when creating an event. However with this solution, the "isOrganizer" property is still set to "true" and I can't find a way to change that. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @WindsorSean, not sure actually. In my workflow, this was not required. So in the UI it's the new organizer and that was enough. But you can try to set this property: 
2.392 PidNameCalendarIsOrganizer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/0f0dbb53-936c-47dc-985d-f0917e0a092c) the same way as the properties above.