# MS Graph C# .Net Create Calendar Event for user with RSVP enabled

Tags: c#, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, .net-4.8

We are currently integrating Microsoft Graph api into a website to create calendar events generated from our system, where users can rsvp to the event.

We are currently using the Auth code flow for authorization for the users.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Where the frontend is a react app, and the backend is a .Net 4.8 C# project.

For our google solution, we create events for every integrated user individually and assign the organizer to be a service email account tied to our site. This allows the users to RSVP to it, and we can track what their status is based on their response. This also allows us to track and delete the individual events on a per user basis when necessary.

When searching and testing for a MS Graph solution, changing the organizer does not work based on the answer here.
[Are the organizer and isOrganizer Attributes in MS-Graph event working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56165042/are-the-organizer-and-isorganizer-attributes-in-ms-graph-event-working)

As when the event is created, the individual that the event was created for is considered the organizer of the event. This is causing the RSVP to not show in outlook.

Is there a way to create an event for a user where the organizer is a generic email account (not an outlook account), while also keeping track of that event Id so we can track the RSVP status, and make any updates when necessary?